# Can't import firebase in AppController

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift, firebase

I am getting this error "Use of '@import' when modules are disabled" when importing Firebase.

```
#import "GameKit/GKLocalPlayer.h"
#import "GameKit/GKScore.h"
#import "GameKit/GKAchievement.h"

@import Firebase;

@implementation AppController
@synthesize viewController;
```

How can I import this properly?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could enable modules in your project's (or target's) build settings and leave it as `@import Firebase;` or you could import using `#import <Firebase/Firebase.h>`

Comment: After change, another error: `'FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore.h' file not found` in `Firebase.h` file. Do you know how to fix it?